# Jmeter - Non HTTP response message: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

Tags: jmeter

Am trying to automate API in Jmeter, wherein getting below error message,

Response code: Non HTTP response code: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

The same request is working fine in Postman, there is a client certificate generated in .CRT or .P79 formats.Also in postman > Certificates i configured Host , CRT file , KEY file, wanted to know in Jmeter where/how we can configure these.

Note : was not able to use openssl and Keytool as am not allowed to install in client machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMeter can only send client certificates if they're present in a [Java Keystore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_KeyStore)

So you need to convert your .crt certificate into .jks or .p12 Java Keystore and tell JMeter where the keystore is located and what is the password using `javax.net.ssl.keyStore` and `javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword` JMeter System Properties like it's described in [How to Set Your JMeter Load Test to Use Client Side Certificates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-set-your-jmeter-load-test-use-client-side-certificates) article.

If you're not capable of installing OpenSSL and/or Keytool to the machine where JMeter lives you can use online certificate conversion solutions like:

- [SSL Converter by SSHShopper](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html)
- [SSL Converter by NameCheap](https://decoder.link/converter/)

Comment: Thanks for your information.This worked.

Below is another issue am facing currently in API test, wherein when running the thread with users more than 3 , am getting response code as 500 - Internal server error ,

setup is as follows,

Thread group Request 1 - Get call (with regular expression controller) Request 2 - Post call (uses above variable from regular expression controller)

Here, Request 2 is Working fine when the Number of Threads(Users) is 1, but fails with response code 500 / Internal server error when its > 3.